# In a bash script, using =~, how do I match the regex ^#.*${new_user}?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Title basically says it all, but I can't figure it out for the life of me and getting confused by bash regular expression matching. This is the `if` statement I have in my bash script, but it keeps matching the line `${new_user}` instead of `# ${new_user}`. I basically want to match a "commented out" user.

```
if [[ $(<"foo.txt") =~ \#.*${new_user} ]]; then
```

Comment: We cannot help if you don't show what you are matching. What is in `foo.txt`? One line? Many lines? What does a match look like? What does a non match look like? Which regex are you actually using? Is it `^#.*${new_user}` as in your title or `\#.*${new_user}` as in the question body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this pattern it's much simpler to not use a regex and just use a glob expression. This is equivalent to `^#.*${new_user}` in your question:

```
% new_user=foo
% [[ '# somethingfoo' == '#'*"${new_user}"* ]]; echo $?
0
% [[ '# somethingbar' == '#'*"${new_user}"* ]]; echo $?
1
```

Since you only anchor on one side in your question, it sounds like you want to match arbitrary characters after `$new_user`. If you actually wanted anchoring at the end, remove the `*`.

While it's certainly possible to use regexes in bash, the ergonomics and footguns present are pretty awkward. Where possible I'd highly recommend to use globs or other mechanisms instead.

If you really need to use regexes, here's how you'd do it (the only difference being to quote `${new_user}` in case it has regex characters):

```bash
$ [[ '# somethingfoo' =~ ^#.*"${new_user}" ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ '# somethingbar' =~ ^#.*"${new_user}" ]]; echo $?
1
```

Again, if you wanted anchoring at the end, add an `$`.

---

It's also possible that you misunderstood what `^` means in a multiline context. In bash, `^` matches the beginning of a string, not the beginning of a line. If you need to look at each line to determine if something is present or not, use `if grep ...; then`, or the following loop instead:

```bash
found=0
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" == '#'*"${new_user}"* ]]; then
        found=1
        break
    fi
done < foo.txt

# do something with $found
```

If you don't care about files with no final newline, you can omit the `[[ $line ]]` check.

Comment: Gotcha thx. So it sounds like using regex in bash rather awkward and cumbersome? That was my impression using it but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Also didn't know ^ in bash regex matches the beginning of the string, not each line. That is actually my problem. I ended up using grep instead.